# JS scope that cannot access its parents scopes

Tags: javascript, scope

Is it possible in Javascript to create an isolated scope within any other scope that cannot access its parent scope's variables and functions, I am thinking of something like this:

```js
// global scope
let a = 'hello';

function shout() {
  console.log('shouting');
}

// an isolated scope
// a scope that is unable to access $a and $shout
(() => {

  console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
  shout(); // ReferenceError: shout is not defined

})();
```

Comment: No. You may be interested in the upcoming ShadowRealm API proposal, though.

Answer (score 3):

No, but you could selectively override the names as arguments or local variables, e.g.:

```js
// global scope
let a = 'hello';

function shout() {
  console.log('shouting');
}

// an isolated scope
// a scope that is unable to access $a and $shout
((a, shout) => {

  console.log(a); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
  shout(); // ReferenceError: shout is not defined

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently no, but in the future though, we might get [ShadowRealms](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-shadowrealm), which allows you to run code in a brand new context (same environment).

Your example could look like

```
let a = 'hello';

function shout() {
  console.log('shouting');
}

const sr = new ShadowRealm();
sr.evaluate(`console.log(a);`);
sr.evaluate(`shout();`);
```

Since this shadow realm does not have an `a` nor a `shout` function defined, this would result in a reference error. I'm not sure how errors are handled in ShadowRealms yet, but it would produce the desired behavior.

You can read more about how to use shadow realms [here](https://2ality.com/2022/04/shadow-realms.html) if they ever get added, or star the proposal [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-shadowrealm) to support it (and hopefully get it added to the standard).

For now you could try something like @canon's answer, or try using worker scripts, but I doubt either of them will produce the behavior you want.

Answer (score 0):

Currently any lower level scope can see everything at higher level, so the answer is currently not.

You can however define your own shielded object:

```js
function shout() {
  console.log('shouting');
}

let whoIsThis = (() => {
  this.name = 'Just me';
  let self = this;
  return {
    set: function(name) {
      self.name = name;
    },
    showMe: function() {
      return 'Who am I? ' + self.name;
    }
  };
})();

(() => {
  shout(); // public scope
  console.log(whoIsThis.showMe());      // 'Who am I? Just me'
  whoIsThis.set('Peter');
  console.log(whoIsThis.showMe());      // 'Who am I? Peter'
  console.log('name:', whoIsThis.name); // 'name: undefined'
})();
```